# I need to read a XML attribute of a tag inside another tag

Tags: php, xml

I was trying to solve it alone but has been passed weeks and I can't solve that...

I have a XML like this one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<clothes>

<clothe premium="no" id="1">
    <list gender="0" style="11" name="Jacket"/>
    <list gender="1" style="12" name="Jacket"/>
</clothe>

<clothe premium="yes" id="2">
    <list gender="0" style="13" name="Pants"/>
    <list gender="1" style="14" name="Pants"/>
</clothe>

</clothes>
```

I want to read on the "clothe" the attributes: 'premium' and 'id'
and on the "list" below it the attributes: 'gender', 'style' and 'name'.

Obs: the best I've ever done was make the php read the first or the last "list" attributes and I need to read all the tags inside the "clothe".

Gender 0 = Male
Gender 1 = Female

Here is an example that I've used and that I need help with:

```
public function getClothes()
{
    $clothes = array();

    foreach( $this->element->getElementsByTagName('list') as $list)
    {
        $clothes[] = $list->getAttribute('gender');
        $clothes[] = $list->getAttribute('style');
        $clothes[] = $list->getAttribute('name');
    }

    return $clothes;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DOM nodes are members of a tree, and are fully aware of their parents/descendants. So... search for the `clothe` elements:

```
$clothes = $this->element->getElementsByTagName('clothe');
foreach($clothes as $clothe) {
    $premium = $clothe->getAttribute('premium');

    $lists = $clothe->getElementsByTagName('list'); // get all `<list>` under the current node
    foreach($lists as $list ) {
         $gender = $list->getAttribute('gender');
         ...
    }
}
```

and once you've got a `<clothe>` element, search for all `<list>` below it.

Comment: Thank you Marc B for answering me and seeing by your point your code is right...

But I don't know why it did not worked for me :/
I use this public function to make an another page insert into a mysql table the data that I got here...

Anyway, if someone else has an another code to help me try it out I'll be thankful!